# Keeping inline <li>'s in place while altering their contents

Tags: css

My site has a navigation bar near the top of the page composed of inline `<li>`'s. The bar itself must be centered. Clicking on the links inside certain of these `<li>`'s replaces the links with `<select>`'s.

My problem is this: when the `<select>`'s appear, they shift all the other `<li>`'s over in order to accommodate their width. Unfortunately, it seems I can't set the width attribute of inline `<li>`'s. I therefore tried making the `<li>`'s float to the left and then assigning a width. This solved the position shifting problem, but now the navigation bar isn't centered!

Could anyone help me figure out the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the `<select>` inside the `<li>` tag you could treat the list item as a container and then absolutely position the select.

`<li><select></select></li>`

and then the css:

`li{position:relative;}`
`select{position:absolute;}`

This way the select will not affect the position of the elements around it.

Comment: But the select might be wider than the li, which would get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `inline-block` option, although that [doesn't work reliably in IE < 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03), as it's only supported for elements that are 'naturally' in-line (which the `select` is, but the `li` itself is not).

Answer (score 0):

Assign widths to your `<li>`s. That solves the shifting, but now you need to center them. So put a container around all those `<li>`s, and center this container. Works in all browsers.

You probably already have a `<ul>` you can use for this purpose, which is probably already inside a `<div>` or something. That would be very convenient. If your markup isn't like that, just wrap another `<div>` around the whole thing and center it.